# In sveltekit, what's the convention for splitting client side code between route files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, sveltekit, conventions

Both `+page.js/ts` and the `<script><script/>` tags within `+page.svelte` files are for processing client side code.

What's the typical convention for choosing between these 2 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been clearly answered in the [Documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing). The separate file is for loading and constructing data that is required by your route, the script tag is for DOM manipulation and client side logic.
That is the convention as per the docs but you are free to use both methods as per your preference but +page.server.js/ts is strictly  for server side logic like authentication and database calls.

Comment: Ok, so I can think of it as +page.ts/js is for preparing/preloading data for the initial display of the page, and <script> tags for subsequently manipulating the page after the initial load.

Comment: Yes for majority of use cases that is true and code should be structured like that. Svelte (Kit) is inherently a very flexible framework and allows you to structure your code as you like it. I had one hobby project in the beginning where I was making all my database calls from the script tag itself before I realized that doing it from the +page.server.js is much faster and simpler.